# Mysql: несколько справочников типов или один универсальный?

Tags: mysql, enum, типы

В Mysql есть несколько таблиц, например, платежи (payment), посещения (visit), логи (log) в каждой из этих таблиц есть свой набор типов (например для платежей это зачисление, оплата товаров, оплата услуг и т. д.). Как лучше хранить эти типы?

Рассматриваю несколько вариантов:

1. Использовать тип *ENUM*
2. Для каждой из таблиц создать таблицу справочник, где будут храниться все возможные типы, и связать по ключу
3. Создать универсальную таблицу справочник, где будут храниться все типы и соответствующие им названия таблиц (например, 1 - payment - зачисление, 2 - visit, вход)

Какой из них наиболее выгоден с точки зрения производительности и возможности расширения списка типов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не возьмусь утверждать, что что-то лучше. Врядли есть единственно правильное решение.

Enum хорош уже тем, что даёт наглядный человекочитаемый результат в выборке *без джойнов* со справочниками. То есть совмещает производительность и наглядность.

С другой стороны, таблицы справочников могут содержать дополнительные атрибуты, кроме собственно идентификатора и расшифровки. Справочники могут использоваться как источник значений для полей выбора в приложении. То есть в простых случаях можно расширить функционал без правок кода.

Универсальность всегда спорит с производительностью, а часто и с удобством. Надо знать меру :) П.М.С.М. универсальный справочник это уже неудобно.

Итого, я бы посоветовал выбирать из (1) и (2) и, возможно, их совмещать. Если вы пользуетесь какими-нибудь "миграциями" совместно с системой контроля версий, то в хозяйстве всегда будет порядок, енумы со справочниками не разойдутся.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, от первого варианта лучше отказаться. Читаемость - единственный его плюс, не самый критичный. Минусов больше. Например: это строковый тип - он всё-таки он медленнее числового; храня там числа, надо быть осторожным, чтобы вместо чисел не получить их индексы - например, считая сумму или там среднее; любое изменение списка - это ALTER TABLE.

Второй и третий вариант почти эквивалентны, но минус третьего в том, что придётся все значения хранить в совместимом типе (строковом, а то и бинарном), что опять же отрицательно скажется на производительности.

Я бы рекомендовал остановиться на варианте "один справочник - одна таблица".

Comment: Внутреннее представление ENUM это целое число. http://stackoverflow.com/q/259547/272885

Comment: Это да. Но часто ли выполняется работа именно с ним? Не говоря уж о том, что сортировка по ENUM полю выполняется именно по индексу, а не по значению - вымораживает насмерть!